# Clean Debian package builded from source

Tags: debian, packages, dpkg

I have build a debian package with:

```
$ dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot
```

now I would like to change the configuration in the .dsc file and build again. How can I clean the files created by the previous build? I tried

```
$dpkg-buildpackage -tc
```

but it seems that doesn't do the job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please use `debuild` instead of calling `dpkg-buildpackage` directly, as that's just one of the steps. Simplest basic method is to build the binary packages along with unsigned source and unsigned changelog, do in the `debian/` directory of the source

```
$ debuild -uc -us
```

You can call the `clean` target on `debuild` to clean up.

```
$ debuild clean
```

Comment: `debuild -- clean` or mine returns `dpkg-buildpackage: error: unknown option or argument clean`